# Find $\mathscr{R}$, given that $\mathscr{R} \neq A \times A$

Tags: functions, relations

An equivalence relation $\mathscr{R}$ defined on a set $A = \{a,b,c,d\}$ contains
the pairs $(a, a), (a, d), (d, b)$.

In my work below: am I going in the correct direction or am I way off on what is being asked?

\begin{align*}
A \times A &= \{a,b,c,d\}\times\{a,b,c,d\}\\
&=[(a,d),(a,b),(a,c),(a,d), \dots]
\end{align*}

[image]

\begin{align*}
A \rightarrow D \rightarrow B \leftarrow A \\
B \rightarrow D \rightarrow A \leftarrow B
\end{align*}

Comment: Your diagram correctly characterizes $\mathcal R$.  Do you know how to write that relation as a set of ordered pairs?

Comment: It's your first day, so I'm gonna cut you some slack. But you should never again delete a question just because it got downvotes and post it anew. You can [edit] a question to incorporate more information. Many users will undo their downvotes if they notice that, and others would upvote if they see a sincere effort on your side.

Comment: @EpsilonNeighborhoodWatch Nicely formatted! Was that Tikz?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, tikz has a very nice automata package for this sort of thing.

Comment: I have not done any mathematics since I finished school 8 years ago...and i barely passed the class. I am now being asked to do the above question with little revision.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom as in (a,a),(a,b),(a,c) and so on..?

Comment: @AsafKaragila my apologies, i deleted it to add in the image. Appreciate the feedback though.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the right idea in your image, but not in your comment.  A correct answer to this question would be
$$
\mathscr R = \\
\{(a,a),(a,b),(a,d)\\
(b,a),(b,b),(b,d)\\
\qquad \quad (d,a),(d,b),(d,d),(c,c)\}
$$
Note, for instance, that $(a,c) \notin \mathscr R$, just as there is no arrow in your diagram from $A$ to $C$.

Comment: So i don't have to draw the diagram? Just answer R= {(a.a), (a,b)... as you have done above ?

Comment: That’s right. As far as I can tell, that’s what they want.